# How to use EVAL to get the last four character of a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code which displays some columns retrieved from a SQL query:

```
<tr class="trOther">
    <td><%# Eval("LastName").ToString() %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("FirstName").ToString() %></td>
    <td><%# Eval("SSN").ToString().Substring(Eval("SSN").ToString().Length - 4, 4) %></td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LastName").ToString() + ", " + Eval("FirstName").ToString() %>' /></td>
</tr>
```

The `SSN` sometime is blank so in that case I would want it to display nothing, otherwise display the last four number of the SSN.

For example:

In `123-12-1234` it will display `1234`

In `123121234` it will display `1234`

In '' it will display '' (column doesn't have a value)

When I run the code I get the following error:

`StartIndex cannot be less than zero`

I am guessing it's because one of the entry it blank. How can I resolve it? (Maybe use a  `:` and `?` to emulate IF/ELSE statement in there?)

Comment: Yes, ternary operator. Or, even better, method in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a below

```
<td><%# Eval("SSN").ToString().Length > 4 ?
    Eval("SSN").ToString().Substring(Eval("SSN").ToString().Length - 4, 4)
   :Eval("SSN").ToString() %></td>
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue is if the number is `123121234` it shows `34` but if it is `123-23-1234` then it shows `1234` so something is not right.

Comment: This code looks right to me.  If you are getting the same result with this code and with my answer, you should probably examine your data more closely.

Comment: @Grax I had two extra spaces on some of the SSN :/ I upvoted your answer and accepted this one as this was simpler to use. Thanks to both of you

Comment: I wonder if you can also assist me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162698/how-to-cascade-dropdowns-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-a-sharepoint-we  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extension method such as the one below and call it like this `<td><%# Eval("SSN").ToString().SafeSmartSubstring(-4,4) %></td>`

```
    public static string SafeSmartSubstring(this string myString, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        var str = (myString ?? "").PadLeft(length);

        if (startIndex < 0)
        {
            startIndex = str.Length + startIndex;
        }

        return str.Substring(startIndex, length).Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Same thing, I am getting the same result as the other answer... :/

Comment: In my test of the edited version (my first post was broken), I get "1234" for both "123121234" and "123-23-1234"